# ODE15s: unable to meet integration tolerances

Tags: matlab

I have to solve
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\ddot{R}=-\frac{3}{2}\frac{\dot{R}^{2}}{R}+\frac{1}{R\rho}\left [P_{v}(T_{\infty})-P_{0}-a_{1}t^{2}-a_{2}t+\frac{(L\rho_{g})^{2}}{hT_{\infty}}\dot{R}-4\mu \frac{\dot{R}}{R}-\frac{2S}{R}  \right ]\\ 
h=\frac{2\hat{\sigma}}{2-\hat{\sigma}}\frac{L^{2}\rho_{g}}{T_{B}}\left ( \frac{\bar{M}}{2\pi \bar{R}T_{B}} \right )^{1/2}\left [ 1-\frac{1}{2L\rho_{g}}\left ( P_{v}(T_{\infty})+\frac{(L\rho_{g})^{2}}{hT_{\infty}}\dot{R} \right ) \right ]\\ 
\ln\left ( \frac{\rho_{g}}{\rho_{c}}\right )=c_{1}\theta^{1/3}+c_{2}\theta^{2/3}+c_{3}\theta^{4/3}+c_{4}\theta^{3}+c_{5}\theta^{37/6}+c_{6}\theta^{71/6}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
where $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
R(0)=R_{0}\\ 
\dot{R}(0)=0\\ 
T_{B}=T_{\infty}+\frac{L\rho_{g}}{h}\dot{R}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

(I do not know if this may be helpful, but note the order of magnitude of $a_{1}$ ($10^{14}$) and of time span ($10^{-6}$).
The problem is that I receive a warning: "Warning: Failure at t=5.142410e-005.  Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value allowed (1.826951e-019) at time t." How can I fix it? I tried switching to ode23t but that did not solve the problem.
[image]

```
function out=densita_20_latente_christ(t,y,R0)
S = 0.073; %N/m
rho = 998;    
mi = 1.005e-3;
P0 = 101325;
L = 2454000;
Tinf = 293;   
lambda = 0.5982;
cp = 4184;   
Pv_Tinf = 2329.6;
sigma_hat=0.03;
M_bar=18;
R_bar=8314;
c1 = -2.03150240;
c2 = -2.6830294;
c3 = -5.38626492;
c4 = -17.2991605;
c5 = -44.7586581;
c6 = -63.9201063;
Tc = 647.096;
rhoc = 322;
a1 = 2.488125e14;
a2 = -9.9525e9;
%
out=[y(2)
    -1.5 * y(2)^2 / y(1) + 1 / rho / y(1) * (Pv_Tinf - a1 * t^2 - a2 * t - P0 +...
    (L * y(4))^2 / Tinf * y(2) / y(3) -...
    4 * mi * y(2) / y(1) - 2 * S / y(1))
     -y(3) + 2 * sigma_hat / (2 - sigma_hat) *...
     L^2 * y(4) / (Tinf + L * y(4) * y(2) / y(3))*...
    (M_bar / (2 * pi * R_bar * (Tinf+ L * y(4) * y(2) / y(3))))^0.5 *...
    (1 - 1 / (2 * L * y(4)) *...
    (Pv_Tinf + (L * y(4))^2 * y(2) / y(3) / Tinf))
    -y(4) + rhoc * exp(c1*(1-1/Tc*(Tinf+y(4)*L/y(3)*y(2)))^(1/3)...
    + c2*(1-1/Tc*(Tinf+y(4)*L/y(3)*y(2)))^(2/3)...
    + c3*(1-1/Tc*(Tinf+y(4)*L/y(3)*y(2)))^(4/3)...
    + c4*(1-1/Tc*(Tinf+y(4)*L/y(3)*y(2)))^(3)...
    + c5*(1-1/Tc*(Tinf+y(4)*L/y(3)*y(2)))^(37/6)...
    + c6*(1-1/Tc*(Tinf+y(4)*L/y(3)*y(2)))^(71/6)) ];
```

run file

```
R0 = 510e-6;
y0 = [510e-6; 0; 11326.8525; 0.01716];
M = [1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0];
options = odeset('Mass',M);
[t,y] = ode15s(@(t,y) densita_20_latente_christ(t,y,R0),[0 52.424e-6],y0,options);
t=t*1000000;
y=y*1000000;
[t,y(:,1)];
plot(t,y(:,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try scaling your problem? If $a_1$ is very large and $t$ is very small, why not scale $t$ (and all the other parameters) accordingly? If $t$ is now expressed in seconds, try to write down the problem in microseconds... $a_1$ and $a_2$ are both large so for $t$ it will work out. I don't know how it will go with the other parameters.

Comment: I scaled his ode such that all coefficients in front of r'^2/r, 1/r, t^2/r, t/r, r'/r, r'/r^2,1/r^2 are all more or less around 1, e.g.   1.5, 1.,  1.,  -2.0053,  0.0049,  0.0020, 0.0074. This does not help. I think there must be something inherently wrong (e.g. a pole as the plot also indicates) when approaching this time.